# AngularJS ui-grid vs Mean.io

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, mean.io

How can I install the angular ui-grid in Mean.io?

I installed with bower without any success, then I installed with npm as well, but `MyPackage.angularDependencies(['uiGrid']);`
is not working.

I saw the downloaded and installed modules inside the folder of bower and npm as well, but my package can not load it.
I get always this error:

> "Error: $injector:modulerr Module Error"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution. Environment:

Ubuntu 14.04, mean.io (0.10.17), bower (1.4.2), npm (2.5.0)

1. run without sudo `$ bower install angular-ui-grid`
2. add *ui.grid.css* and *ui-grid.min.js* files to **config/assets.json**
3. add

   > yourApp.angularDependencies(['ui.grid']);

   to your *app.js* file
4. restart npm

now it's working :-)